# Form validation plugin fails with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a validator plugin that I have built, and with each problem solved it seems a new one is appearing. The currently problem is that when I use a class as the validation selector, anything with that class is validated and as long as one of them is filled in then it is accepted. Now, while this is probably okay for some instances, it is not for all.

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/9gwuyras/2/

The full code for the validation plugin can be found in the fiddle as well.

**parts of the code where I think the issue is being caused**

Using the Fiddle as reference for lines of code
`Lines 497 - 514`

Reasoning it probably doesn't matter that the class selector is in the setting.selectors[] array multiple times, but it is a possible option:

```
for(var control in controls){
    if(typeof controls[control] != 'object'){
        console.log("controls."+control+" must be an object. Skipping this element");
        continue;
    }else if(typeof controls[control].validate == 'undefined'){
        console.log("controls."+control+".validate must be defined");
        continue;
    }
    $this.find('input, textarea, select').each(function(){
        if($(this).is('#'+control)){
            setControlData('#'+control, controls[control]);
            settings.selectors.push('#'+control);   
        }else if($(this).hasClass(control)){
            setControlData('.'+control, controls[control]);
            settings.selectors.push('.'+control);
        }
    });
}
```

`Lines: 397 to 401`

Reasoning is that it might be targeting just any form group of that class selector and not the focus:

```
var formGroup = null;
if(type != "radio" && type != "checkbox"){
    formGroup = $(element).closest('.form-group');
    value = $(element).val();
}
```

That's what I have this far.

### Edit

I forgot the most important piece to the situation, how the plugin is called:

```
$('#test').validator({
    controls : {
        name : {
            validate : "notEmpty"
        },
        dob : {
            validate : ['notEmpty', 'isDateTime'],
            dateFormat : 'm/d/Y'
        },
        gender : {
            validate : "notEmpty"
        }
    },
    bindInput : true,
    onSubmit : function(){}
});
```

The keys in the `controls` object can either be an id or a class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read you're trying to create a plugin that validates either an id or class on a form.

You stated:

> The currently problem is that when I use a class as the validation selector, anything with that class is validated and as long as one of them is filled in then it is accepted.

This is happening because once your plugin is triggered it 'loops'(your each loop) through anything matching that class... even if the element wrapped in that class is only filled out once (and there are multiple other instances of it).

You have many options, my recommendation is either: 1) Remove the ability for the plugin to call a class or 2) Validate the class by checking it's state. Right now it will just go through and try to validate everything when it should be validating only a class based on state (checked, unchecked, .val etc.).